# IMPORTXML can't fetch from Yahoo Finance if there is a point in in the ticker

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

Basically, the title: I can fetch data from Yahoo Finance for `ASML` ticker by

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASML/", "//*[@id=""quote-header-info""]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]")
```

But it doesn't work if there is a point/dot "`.`" in the ticker:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASML.AS/", "//*[@id=""quote-header-info""]/div[3]/div[1]/div/span[1]")
```

returning the infamous

> #N/A

error. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what the problem is and how I can resolve it.

**P.S.1**  Please note that the above URLs are both valid and point towards different stocks.

**P.S.2.** I wrote a relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68413356/4999991).

**P.S.3.** [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66547974/4999991) also identified the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why all tickers with dots are not returning properly, but you can try using Apps Script as alternative via `UrlFetchApp.fetch` and use this custom function I created.

Script:

```
function customImportXML(link) {
  var regex = /span class="Trsdu\(0.3s\) Fw\(b\) Fz\(36px\) Mb\(-4px\) D\(ib\)"[^>]*>([^<]*)</g;
  return regex.exec(UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getContentText())[1];
}
```

I used the class as identifier as the `data-reactid` is not permanent.

[image: output]

Comment: Hi @Foad, there is an option below that let's you proceed. It says unsafe and continue i believe. Just allow the script to have permission and you should be able to use that.

Comment: No there isn't any option to do anything. This is a prevalent issue apparently with no clear solution as far as I can see.